# How to generate a sequence of numbers that can later be used in the command lines in python?

Tags: python, numbers, range

what I want to do is to write a script wich get some files as input and then run some command on them! I first want to know how many files dose the user has and then ask for him/her to upload it and later I want to run some command on it.
So I had used this command: `for cnt in`seq 19 2 31 in a similar situation long time ago but now when I use this command I get a syntex error!
this is my comand:

```
readnumber= raw_input("How many pares do you have?" )
for cnt in `seq 1 1 int(readnumber)`; do
    pare$cnt-a = raw_input("filename of pare$cnt-a: ")
    pare$cnt-b = raw_input("filename of pare$cnt-b: ")
    cmd = "samtools merge   pare$cnt.bam pare$cnt-a pare$cnt-b"
```

And this is the error that I get:

```
>         for cnt in 'seq 1 1 int(readnumber)'; do
>                                             ^
>     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so what I expext is when you put the readnumber=3 then it ask you to upload (or input) this:

```
pare1-a:
pare1-b:
pare2-a:
pare2-b:
pare3-a:
pare3-b:
```

and then run my command on it!

Comment: You are confusing what seems to be Bash shell script syntax with Python...

Comment: Are you mixing bash syntax with python ?

Comment: ya I think so! ok that's why it doesn't work! any idea how can I do this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
pairs = int(raw_input("How many pairs do you have?"))
for pair_n in xrange(1, pairs + 1):
  file1 = raw_input("pair%d-a: " % pair_n)
  file2 = raw_input("pair%d-b: " % pair_n)
  cmd = "samtools merge pair%d.bam '%s' '%s'" % (pair_n, file1, file2)
  # os.system(cmd) to run the command.
```

Comment: @mahmood : This seems to be the Python way to get what you wanted. If you really want to run a Bash command from python, you could use `os.system(command)` or `subprocess.popen(command)`, for example (Google these for examples, if necessary).

Comment: thanks a lot! no I wanted to use the python but I mixed it with my old bash command! thanks for the answer it's what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up Python with bash scripting. `raw_input` is Python, but everything else in the script is bash.

Rather than trying to rewrite the whole thing in Python, it seems like you should just use bash, maybe with the `read` command instead of raw_input.

Comment: I agree with @DanielRoseman except that I would take the opportunity to learn Python, since it is more powerful than bash to some tasks (but of course not every task). Actually, in a linux system, mixing Python and Bash THE RIGHT WAY is a very powerful way to acomplish trivial and non-trivial tasks easily and quickly.

Comment: yes I understand my mistake! but I want to write it in python. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use bash syntax in a python program.  They are different languages.  For instance, the `seq` command should instead be an `xrange(...)` command.  You are also using bash variable syntax `$somevar` instead of python's variable syntax.

So either use bash or use Python, but don't try to mix-n-match.

And you may want to consider having the user provide the filenames on the commandline, rather than prompting the user for them.  That will make your script more useful as a building block later.

Answer (score 0):

The `for`-line of yours it not Python-code, it's a for-statement used in `bash`-shells.

What you want to do is to rewrite the for-line into this:

```
for cnt in range(1, readnumber):
```

Also, you will have to rewrite the other lines as well, since they are bash-syntax too.